# How to remain a code active after all macros have been executed

Tags: vba, excel

I have written multiple macros that will be executed with a command button however I want my last macro to remain active after all before macros have been executed. I want Macro15 to remain active after. And for for Macro15 I want if any cell changes I want to highlight that cell with colorindex 3

```
Sub RunallMacros()
macro1
macro2
macro3
macro5
Macro12
Macro13
Macro14
Macro15
End Sub




Sub macro1()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate

End Sub

Sub macro2()
Dim myvalue As Variant
myvalue = InputBox("Enter Safety Stock Days")
Range("R5").value = myvalue

End Sub

Sub macro5()

Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Are There Any ICF Forms?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Other Sales")
If answer = vbYes Then ICFUserForm.Show



End Sub

Sub macro3()
Dim MyAnswer1 As Variant
Dim MyAnswer2 As Variant
Dim MyAnswer3 As Variant
Dim MyAnswer4 As Variant
Dim MyAnswer5 As Variant

MyAnswer1 = InputBox("Enter Growth Current Month")
Range("m3").value = MyAnswer1


MyAnswer2 = InputBox("Enter Growth Current Month+1")
Range("n3").value = MyAnswer2


MyAnswer3 = InputBox("Enter Growth Current Month+2")
Range("o3").value = MyAnswer3


MyAnswer4 = InputBox("Enter Growth Current Month+3")
Range("p3").value = MyAnswer4


MyAnswer5 = InputBox("Enter Growth Current Month+4")
Range("q3").value = MyAnswer5

End Sub

Sub Macro12()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='raw data'!R[-5]C"
    Range("A7").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A7:A500"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub

Sub Macro13()
      Range("C7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub

Sub Macro14()
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Raw" And ws.Name <> "Main" And ws.Name <> "Calendar" Then
        For Each c In ws.Range("A50:A300")
            ws.Rows(c.Row).Hidden = c.value = 0
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub

Sub Macro15()
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Or _
  Not Intersect(Target, Range("A7:AH500")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a lot of code.  Can you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE) of what you are trying to accomplish?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great answer from Paul - try this to get it working;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target as Range) 

      Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 


End Sub
```

Comment: great now could I set this on a module, or would this code go on ThisWorkbook

Comment: I would say if you don't have much background in VBA, just try the following in the ThisWorkbook object; `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target as Range) 

      Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 

End Sub`

Comment: I have added this to myworkbook and changed a value in any of the sheet with no highlighting any suggestions?

Comment: Okay try this - Delete what you've just added to the ThisWorkbook object. Then with the drop-downs select 'Workbook' from the left hand one, and 'SheetChange' from the right hand one. It should insert some code. Inside the Sub (before the End Sub code) - Add  the ` Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ` code.

Comment: perfect! Thanks for your patience

Comment: Ah good - glad it worked! I've answered the same on your other thread - if you could mark that one as answered to close it down.

Answer (score 2):

A macro that is "active" is doing something, i.e. it is executing code. While it is executing code, the user can't do anything. So either the macro is active or the user is active.

What you want is to respond to an event, in this case the `Worksheet.Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
End Sub
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: can I add this to a module, or does this have to go on a sheet directly?

Comment: You should try it. I expect it must be attached to the ThisWorkbook object and then it would fire for changes on all worksheets. Attaching it to only a Worksheet object will make it fire for only that worksheet.

Comment: I have added it to my workbook and I go to any sheet and it will no highlight any suggestions?

Comment: I said __you should TRY it__. I tried it and found out in 1 minute how it works. I leave it up to you as an excercise. So what is next if it doesn't fire on the Workbook level?

Comment: Thanks for having a teacher, student moment except I come with no background in vba, however I appreciate your help.

Comment: I assume you attached it now to the Worksheet and it worked?